# Bouncing ball misses some platforms when colliding

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am trying to create a demo game just like Doodle Jump and i am stuck in the most silly case. My bouncing ball just misses some platforms (falls through) when checking for collision.

Any ideas on that? Codepen follows for help.

I've tried sorting the platforms in the array (thinking that this was the error), to no avail of course.

Here is my codepen example for showing the case.
https://codepen.io/v4vaios/pen/ZEzpozg

```
    checkPlatformCollision(platforms) {
    if (goingDown) {

      for(let j=0; j<platforms.length; j++) {
        let distX = Math.abs(this.x - platforms[j].x-platformWidth/2);
        let distY = Math.abs(this.y - platforms[j].y-platformHeight/2);
        let dx=distX-platformWidth/2;
        let dy=distY-platformHeight;

        if (dx*dx + dy*dy <= (this.r*this.r)) {
          return true
        }


      }
    }

    return false
  }
```

Comment: Best I can tell, your collision detection only works on the edge of the platform. When the ball hits the center of your platform, it falls through. When it hits the edge of a platform, it detects the collision.

Comment: Hm... that sounds interesting.... could you please indicate the exact collision detection code that would prevent such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made several flaws there :

1. Your collision detector don't works when ball goes UP (no need for check `if (goingDown)`), because collision may occur on ball traveling ANY direction.
2. Second flaw is that you are measuring distance from ball center to rectangle center. When ball will collide with far side of rectangle you will not detect collision. Like this:
   [image]

`dist <= r` is FALSE, so no collision detected

What you need is to calculate circle centers distance to NEAREST point on rectangle, like this:

[image]

When ball will reach rectangle, dist <= r will be TRUE.

While fixing these flaws, we get such collision detection function:

```
checkPlatformCollision(platforms) {

      for(let j=0; j<platforms.length; j++) {
      let NearestX = Math.max(platforms[j].x, Math.min(this.x, platforms[j].x + platformWidth));
      let NearestY = Math.max(platforms[j].y, Math.min(this.y, platforms[j].y + platformHeight));

        let dx = Math.abs(this.x - NearestX);
        let dy = Math.abs(this.y - NearestY);

        if (dx*dx + dy*dy <= (this.r*this.r)) {
          return true;
        }

       }

      return false;

  }
```

Comment: This was actually the opposite of what I found, namely that collision detection only worked on the edges, not the center.

Comment: This depends on whenever distance displacements `let dx=distX-platformWidth/2;
        let dy=distY-platformHeight;` are included or not in the code. In any way, it either works on edges or center of rectangle, but not on both (or not on rectangle any surface point to be precisely correct). So clearly distance calculation was _incorrect_.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that making the following changes fixed the problem. Now the collision detection works just fine.

`checkPlatformCollision(platforms) {
    for(let j=0; j<platforms.length; j++) {
      if (
        (goingDown) &&
        (this.x < platforms[j].x + platformWidth) &&
        (this.x + this.r > platforms[j].x) &&
        (this.y + this.r > platforms[j].y) &&
        (this.y + this.r < platforms[j].y + platformHeight)
        ) {
          return true
      }
    }
    return false
  }`